# StackSIdebar is not visible

Tags: development, vala, gtk, apps

I used Gtk.StackSidebar to create a sidebar for an app that I am making.
https://github.com/Suzie97/Project_X97, this is the link to my github repo.

The sidebar is not correctly visible on the window. The entire window is captured by one button and the other button is not visible.

[image]

Can anyone review the code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `stack` to the window:
https://github.com/Suzie97/Project_X97/blob/4506489bbe5d79343728e6259d614dacc4b2036d/Project_X97/src/Window.vala#L64

You are then constructing an object called `grid` that you're packing the StackSidebar into, but then the grid doesn't get added to the window.

So you probably need `add (grid)` instead.